# How to get blob to a string in Node,js with azure

Tags: node.js, azure

I am trying to download a blob from a windows azure blob storage, straight to a string. Currently I can get it to a file. But can not find any documentation of how to get the data straight to a variable.

```
blobService.getBlobToStream('ratings'
        , '0001'
        , fs.createWriteStream('output.txt')
        , function(error){
        if(!error){
            // Wrote blob to stream
            console.log("blob written");
        }
    });
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a function called [`getBlobToText`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L1592) in node.js SDK (Source code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js). Give that a try.